# IntelliJ IDEA: Open build tool window

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, build, window

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 and Maven for building my project. I've set "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven".
Is it possible to automatically open a Build tool window when I build the project or a module?
Something like "open run/debug tool window when started" option on application run configurations.

Comment: I think the IDEA doesn't have this feature. But you could try to record a [macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) which shows the Build tool window first and build this project.

Comment: Why do you need that? You can build within your IDE and starting can be done as welll from your ide?

Comment: @floatingcat Thanks. That work surprisingly great. :)

Comment: @khmarbaise Because I want to see what build is doing.

Comment: Start the command line either directly from your OS or start a terminal in your IDE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the solution [floating-cat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2331527/floating-cat) provided:
I think the IDEA doesn't have this feature. But you could try to record a [macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) which shows the Build tool window first and build this project.